# Destination /home/developer/.conan/conan.conf does not exist

Tags: ansible, config, ansible-inventory, conan

I am building ansible-core project, but due to following code snipped getting error

```
# This was necessary to prevent errors when upgading conan from an earlier to a newer version, as the accepted file format changed.
- name: Make conan storage path absolute
  lineinfile:
    path: '{{ HOME }}/.conan/conan.conf'
    regexp: '^path ='
    line: path = ./data
```

Error-

```
TASK [Make conan storage path absolute] ****************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Destination /home/developer/.conan/conan.conf does not exist !", "rc": 257}
```

I tried commenting that part and was able to build but not sure whether to remove that code snippet

Comment: Not sure how that ansible is provisioning or the reasons for it, but I can explain the "/data" folder inside the cache is the one storing the installed packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved issue by changing path from
'{{ HOME }}' to '~'

```
# This was necessary to prevent errors when upgading conan from an earlier to a 
newer version, as the accepted file format changed.

- name: Make conan storage path absolute
  lineinfile:
    path: '{{ HOME }}/.conan/conan.conf'
    regexp: '^path ='
    line: path = ./data
```